# IInAppBillingService Object is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-billing

I'm trying to use Android In App Billing by following google documents. But I tried to use bindService method for using InAppBillingService Object (mService). It returns true, but mService is still null. here is my code

public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn;
ArrayList<String> skuList;
Bundle querySkus;
Bundle skuDetails;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);


    Log.d("payment", "isBillingAvailable? " + isBillingAvailable(this));

    String chargeString = getIntent().getStringExtra("charge");

    Log.d("intentTest", "charge is: " + chargeString);

    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

            Log.d("Payment", "service disconnected!");

            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Log.d("Payment", "service connected!");
        }
    };


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to IInAppBillingService
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    this.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);



    try{
        while(mService == null){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Log.d("payment", "sleep 1 second");
        }

    }catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
    skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");
    skuList.add("gas");
    querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
}

public static boolean isBillingAvailable(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

}

I know it is vert bad code because bindService is called in onCreate. But I tried it on Asyn and there was no change. I tried to wait until connection is completed by sleeping mainTread. This try makes my App in infinited Loop.

my error message is

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.bigsapp.www/kr.co.bigsapp.www.activities.PaymentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getSkuDetails(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference

Please help me TT

Comment: error message occurs when annotate sleep loop

Comment: There is no `bindService()` call in the posted code. Please edit your question.

Comment: sry.. i removed it when i edit code

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (looping until `mService` is non-null) is flawed. In fact, that's what's preventing the service from being created.

The creation of a local, "in-process" `Service` does not happen synchronously with the `bindService()`/`startService()` call. You have to return control to the framework; in this case, that means returning from `onStart()`. This is because the state of the `Service` is advanced by the message queue (`Looper`) that is running on the main thread, and while you're stuck in `onStart()`, that `Looper` isn't "looping".

If you return, you'll find that `Service.onCreate()` and `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` are called within a few milliseconds.